# Google Teachable Machine Javascript Code not working on Raspberry PI

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, teachable-machine

I have a Google Teachable Machine Project with multiple classes in Javascript for my Raspberry PI and i coppied it just like this:

```
<div>Teachable Machine Image Model</div>
<button type="button" onclick="init()">Start</button>
<div id="webcam-container"></div>
<div id="label-container"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.3.1/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/image@0.8/dist/teachablemachine-image.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // More API functions here:
    // https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/image

    // the link to your model provided by Teachable Machine export panel
    const URL = "./my_model/";

    let model, webcam, labelContainer, maxPredictions;

    // Load the image model and setup the webcam
    async function init() {
        const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
        const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";

        // load the model and metadata
        // Refer to tmImage.loadFromFiles() in the API to support files from a file picker
        // or files from your local hard drive
        // Note: the pose library adds "tmImage" object to your window (window.tmImage)
        model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
        maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();

        // Convenience function to setup a webcam
        const flip = true; // whether to flip the webcam
        webcam = new tmImage.Webcam(200, 200, flip); // width, height, flip
        await webcam.setup(); // request access to the webcam
        await webcam.play();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        // append elements to the DOM
        document.getElementById("webcam-container").appendChild(webcam.canvas);
        labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) { // and class labels
            labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        }
    }

    async function loop() {
        webcam.update(); // update the webcam frame
        await predict();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    // run the webcam image through the image model
    async function predict() {
        // predict can take in an image, video or canvas html element
        const prediction = await model.predict(webcam.canvas);
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
            const classPrediction =
                prediction[i].className + ": " + prediction[i].probability.toFixed(2);
            labelContainer.childNodes[i].innerHTML = classPrediction;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This way, it yells: jsx. component must have one parent element. But if i wrap it into a parent element, it yelles "unexpected token".
At the moment, the file ending is .js , but i have tried every refactoring with .js as well as with .jsx .
Btw. I would like to switch to python, but I need to work with js, because the backend as well as the frontend work with js. The IDE is VSC.
Do you see any mistake or know how I could solve it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `webcam.canvas` cannot open the Raspberry camera and take a picture.
So you have to replace this with code that is suitable for the Raspberry Pi and its camera.